# Error al hacer git add

Tags: git

Estoy aprendiendo a manejar git, uso el entorno de Visual Studio 2019 y al hacer cualquier tipo de cambio en un proyecto e intentar hacer un "git add ." me salta el siguiente error:

```
    error: open(".vs/PROGRAMA PRACTICA 2/v16/Browse.VC.opendb"): Permission denied
    error: unable to index file '.vs/PROGRAMA PRACTICA 2/v16/Browse.VC.opendb'
    fatal: adding files failed
```

Solo me pasa si a la hora de ejecutar el comando tengo la solución del proyecto abierta, si cierro la aplicación me deja ejecutarlo sin problemas, pero claro, quiero poder hacerlo con la solución abierta, ¿alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¿Has probado usando las herramientas **Team explorer** del **visual studio**. Con ellas te puedes **Conectar** al repositorio **git** (u otros posibles), y directamente tendrás las opciones de sincronizar, actualizar, etc...

Comment: Te lo comento, porque es normal que por comando algunas cosas no funcionan porque el visual studio puede estar usando ya esos ficheros y no se puede escribir en ellos desde otro lugar...

Comment: para agregar todos los archivos?

Comment: por otra parte, ese tipo de archivos que hay en la carpeta .vs/ son del editor. Esa carpeta deberia estar añadida en el .gitignore, pues no son archivos del proyecto en si, sino del editor que usas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay directorios que no son necesarios subir a GIT ya que sólo ocuparían espacio y generarían errores, este es el caso de los archivos de caché de VisualStudio (directorio `.vs`).

La solución es agregar un archivo `.gitignore` con:

```
.vs/
```

O agregar esa línea si ya tienes un gitignore.

O incluso mejor, usar el gitignore sugerido por GitHub para VisualStudio (o lenguajes de programación específicos).

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

Comment: Probaré eso a ver si me funciona, muchas gracias :)